# How to prevent "There appears to be a discrepancy between the solution's source control..." without changing the .sln file

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs, version-control

Note: I saw ["There appears to be a discrepancy between the solution's source control ...."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/211839/there-appears-to-be-a-discrepancy-between-the-solutions-source-control) , but this doesn't apply, as I wish to fix this *without* changing the .sln file.

For some reason, any time I open a solution which has in the sln file:

```
SccTeamFoundationServer = http://servername:8080/tfs/defaultcollection
SccAuxPath* = http://servername:8080/tfs/defaultcollection
```

My copy of VSS insists on switching it to

```
SccTeamFoundationServer = http://servername:8080/tfs/
SccAuxPath* = http://servername:8080/tfs/
```

Saving these changes *does* fix everything for me, but everyone else using the same version control server is fine with the 1st version but not the second version.  I wish for my computer's version control server/paths to be consistent with that of my coworkers.

Everyone is using Visual Studio 2010 with Visual Studio 2010 Team Explorer.

Comment: I figured out the answer to this question just by coincidence see the following question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16616424/there-appears-to-be-a-discrepancy-between-the-solutions-source-control-informat

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I had this problem with a Solution containing *.vcxproj project files, that were previously migrated from VS2008 to VS2010.
The path to TFS was defined in both the .sln file and the .vcxproj files.

The simplest fix was to update the *.vcxproj project files to use the SAK keyword.

ie update from the format:

```
<SccProjectName>$/MyProject/Directory/abc</SccProjectName>
<SccAuxPath>http://servername:8080/tfs/defaultcollection</SccAuxPath>
<SccLocalPath>.</SccLocalPath>
<SccProvider>{11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111}</SccProvider>
```

to

```
<SccProjectName>SAK</SccProjectName>
<SccAuxPath>SAK</SccAuxPath>
<SccLocalPath>SAK</SccLocalPath>
<SccProvider>SAK</SccProvider>
```

Comment: I think this relates to the problem, but the error stopped happening without me noticing, so I'm not fully confident in that.

Comment: this exactly fixed my problem.  I had a single csproj that wasn't using "SAK" for those 4 items, and modifying it took care of the issue.

Comment: Bingo - same here.  One project did not have those settings as "SAK".  Changed them and it removed the issue.

Comment: What does the `SAK` keyword mean? And why does it solve the issue?

Comment: @JanNilsFerner - Ok, but how does it solve the issue?

Comment: @Matt If I understand it correctly, it will let the project use the connection information that has already been defined in the solution.

Comment: @JanNilsFerner - That would make sense. Thank you for the hint!

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried connecting to http://servername:8080/tfs/defaultcollection instead of http://servername:8080/tfs/ in your Team Explorer settings - Team Project Connection?  Try to do that, let someone who have the http://servername:8080/tfs/ version check-in, remap your local instance then get latest.

Comment: I get an error, "TF249001: You have specified the URL for a project collection, but the application instance that contains the project collection will be added instead."

Answer (score 2):

I just had this exact problem. I finally solved the issue by disconnecting from TFS and reconnecting:
In Team Explorer (View-Team Explorer), right-click on your TFS server name and click 'Disconnect'. Then click Team-Connect to Team Foundation Server...

I did not have any pending changes when I did this.  I would check in your code or at least shelve your changes before doing this to decrease the chance of losing work.

The computer that this happened on had been working fine for over a year, but I guess Visual Studio somehow cached the name as http://servername:8080/tfs/ instead of http://servername:8080/tfs/defaultcollection and disconnecting and reconnecting to TFS reset VS to the correct path of http://servername:8080/tfs/defaultcollection. On my server (and I would guess on everyone's) http://servername:8080/tfs/ and http://servername:8080/tfs/defaultcollection point to the same thing. Raymund's solution didn't work for me - I had the same problem that Brian had with it.

Comment: I have the exact same problem, but what you suggest isn't possible in VS2015.

Answer (score 2):

Using Visual Studio you can solve this problem by unbinding and binding the solution and/or projects. Try this:

1. Open the problem solution in VS (did this in VS2013 just now)
2. Commit anything you need to commit (let's keep it simple - nothing to merge/checkin)
3. If there are any pending changes then undo all pending changes to all the projects in that solution and any changes to the solution itself
4. Go to File -> Source Control -> Advanced -> Change Source Control
5. Select the problem projects and click "Unbind"
6. Click OK and close the window (**THIS IS IMPORTANT - if you don't click OK VS doesn't update the solution properly**)
7. Go to File -> Source Control -> Advanced -> Change Source Control
8. Select all the projects you unbound in #5 and click "Bind"
9. Click OK and close the window
10. Check in your Solution & Project changes
11. Close the solution and open it back up and everything should be fine now

Comment: this method gave exactly the same result as the one described in the accepted answer; however, it's less error prone and faster for multiple project, therefore recommended. Especially it should help with whatever else might be added in the configs later on and easier to remember :)

Answer (score 0):

Also try opening the .sln file from Source Control Explorer, I think that may have been what solved the issue for me.