# Visual Studio removes TFS DefaultCollection path from the solution file

Tags: visual-studio-2015, tfs

I have a solution which is versioned in TFS. I'm using Visual Studio 2015 U3.

Sometimes the sln file is automatically checked out and only change is about SccTeamFoundationServer

For some reason/setting it is changing TFS server URL from:

```
https://tfs.mydomain.com/tfs/defaultcollection
```

To:

```
https://tfs.mydomain.com/tfs
```

This is annoying since many others work on this solution and when they work on it VS is changing it back to /defaultcollection. Is there some setting to control this?

Comment: We've suspected a registry setting causing this for Administrator user. This problem occurred when VS was run by right click and "Run as Administrator"

Answer (score 0):

The issue is similar to this one: [How to prevent "There appears to be a discrepancy between the solution's source control..." without changing the .sln file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5720265/how-to-prevent-there-appears-to-be-a-discrepancy-between-the-solutions-source)

You could go through your project files and update the `*.xxproj` project files to use the **SAK** keyword which are used to store the source control bindings of a project.

> ie update from the format:
>
> ```
> <SccProjectName>$/MyProject/Directory/abc</SccProjectName>
> <SccAuxPath>http://servername:8080/tfs/defaultcollection</SccAuxPath>
> <SccLocalPath>.</SccLocalPath>
> <SccProvider>{11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111}</SccProvider>
> ```
>
> to
>
> ```
> <SccProjectName>SAK</SccProjectName>
> <SccAuxPath>SAK</SccAuxPath>
> <SccLocalPath>SAK</SccLocalPath>
> <SccProvider>SAK</SccProvider>
> ```

If above is not working another way is trying to remove the automatically checking out in VS. Open the solution file and if there are below section in the file, removed it, checked in the solution, closed then re-opened it.

```
GlobalSection(ExtensibilityGlobals) = postSolution
    MyGlobalProperty = AnyValue
EndGlobalSection
```