# There appears to be a discrepancy between the solution's source control information about some project(s) and the information in the project file(s)

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

I get this error message in a Reporting Services solution in Visual Studio 2010 [we're using TFS for source control]:

> There appears to be a discrepancy between the solution's source
>   control information about some project(s) and the information in the
>   project file(s).
>
> To resolve this discrepancy it will be necessary to check out the
>   project file(s) and update them. If the check out fails, however, and
>   the solution is closed without saving, you will see this warning again
>   the next time you open the solution.

Only some projects get checked out but others seem OK. So here is what I tried:

1. I tried to compare what might be different between the project
   files that work and don't work but nothing catches my eye.
2. I looked around and tried a
   number of proposed solutions like "adding a file, checking in and then removing
   it and checking in". No luck.
3. I tried to look for "Scc" tags in project files
   but I don't see any in there. I also don't see them in projects that
   work fine. Looking at my solution the Scc entries look reasonable.

Help!! What am I missing?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to prevent "There appears to be a discrepancy between the solution's source control..." without changing the .sln file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5720265/how-to-prevent-there-appears-to-be-a-discrepancy-between-the-solutions-source)

Comment: A slightly different solution at [Visual Studio solution TFS check in](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20968233/visual-studio-solution-tfs-check-in)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Using Visual Studio you can solve this problem by unbinding and binding the solution and/or projects. Try this:

1. Open the problem solution in VS (did this in VS2013 just now)
2. Undo all pending changes to all the projects in that solution and the solution itself
3. Go to File -> Source Control -> Advanced -> Change Source Control
4. Select the problem projects and click "Unbind"
5. Click OK and close the window (**THIS IS IMPORTANT - if you don't click OK VS doesn't update the solution properly**)
6. Go to File -> Source Control -> Advanced -> Change Source Control
7. Select all the projects you unbound in #4 and click "Bind"
8. Click OK and close the window
9. Check In Your Changes
10. Close the solution and open it back up and everything should be fine now

Comment: The bold is essential. To figure out which project has the problem select "Source control - Team Foundation" in the Output window in VS and see which of your project files "...has been automatically checked out for editing." each time that you open your solution.

Comment: I've just had this and it's been driving me up the wall.  Nice one, Denis.

Comment: Unfortunately, in **VS 2015** this menu item "unbind" seems to no longer exist.

Answer (score 10):

Experienced the same problem in VS2015.

I found this workaround worked for me:

> Change < Scc* > tag values to "SAK" (Should already know) in the project files:

```
<SccProjectName>SAK</SccProjectName>
<SccProvider>SAK</SccProvider>
<SccAuxPath>SAK</SccAuxPath>
<SccLocalPath>SAK</SccLocalPath>
```

https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/616751/discrepancy-between-the-solutions-source-control-information-about-some-project-s-and-the-information-in-the-project-file-s

Workaround #3

Comment: In which file did you edit this? Project? Solution? I am asking this since I got the same error message with a web project.

Comment: I modified the project files

Comment: FYI: this is what Visual Studio does when it you unbind/bind the projects.

Comment: In my experience unbind/bind doesn't change the values to SAK. I had to manually edit the project file.

Answer (score 0):

There was 1 person on our team who was doing the conversion to TFS from VSS who didn't have any errors. He never checked in his solution so we never saw it until now. I looked through his solution file and there are differences. I found the following differences for each project in "GlobalSection(TeamFoundationVersionControl) = preSolution":

Our NETReports.sln in TFS (the file that gave the error above):

```
SccProjectUniqueName7 = EllinReports\\DiagnosticReports\\DiagnosticReports.rptproj
SccProjectName7 = EllinReports/DiagnosticReports
SccLocalPath7 = EllinReports\\DiagnosticReports
```

His NETReports.sln (the file that DOESN'T give the error above):

```
SccProjectUniqueName7 = Reports\\DiagnosticReports\\DiagnosticReports.rptproj
SccProjectTopLevelParentUniqueName7 = NETReports.sln
SccProjectName7 = Reports/DiagnosticReports
SccAuxPath7 = http://<server>:8081/tfs/dev
SccLocalPath7 = Reports\\DiagnosticReports
SccProvider7 = {4CA58AB2-18FA-4F8D-95D4-32DDF27D184C}
```

I guess it all makes sense now. We were all missing the SccAuxPathXXX, SccProviderXXX and SccProjectTopLevelParentUniqueNameXXX. Having them made the difference.