# There appears to be a discrepancy between the solution's source control information

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

when I open VS 2017, I get this warning message:

> There appears to be a discrepancy between the solution's source
>   control information.

It seems there's some change in .sln file, in particulary tfs server path.

Originaly: http://servername:8080/tfs/defaultcollection
New: http://servername:8080/tfs/

Is there a way how to resolve the problem without a change in the .sln file?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 1):

There should be something wrong with your source control binding.

You could try to unbind/bind your project.

Another workaround for you:

> Change < Scc* > tag values to "SAK" (Should already know) in the project files:

```
<SccProjectName>SAK</SccProjectName>
<SccProvider>SAK</SccProvider>
<SccAuxPath>SAK</SccAuxPath>
<SccLocalPath>SAK</SccLocalPath>
```

More detail way please take a look at this link: [There appears to be a discrepancy between the solution's source control information about some project(s) and the information in the project file(s)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16616424/there-appears-to-be-a-discrepancy-between-the-solutions-source-control-informat)